# How to set reload function keep running in the background or when switch the tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I currently have a requirement, to somehow refresh a particular tab on chrome after few intervals. I have written my code at popup.js and made a page of popup.html to reflect a single input of interval in minutes and have a start and stop button. From there I get the tab id of 0, and utilize setInterval to reload the page continuously after certain interval and that works fine. However, when I switch tab, the reload stops working altogether. I am trying to understand is there a need of background.js for this to dispatch the listener event to keep loading for particular tabId? If so would there be any good example to go through as of how to keep refreshing the tab even when I switch the tab?

Comment: The popup runs only when shown so yes you need a background script to run the timers regardless of the popup visibility.

Comment: So technically the logic I wrote in popup, I can switch to background script and just have the accessors setup at popup that send the message to the background script to get the timers going.. does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, the popup will only have a UI + messaging.